# sqlplus invalid indentifier of INT data type

Tags: oracle, ddl

I want to create a table customer with the following attributes

1. custId
2. custName
3. custAge

I wrote my Create table like this

```
SQL > CREATE TABLE Customer (
 2  custId INT NOT NULL,
 3  custName VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
 4  custAge INT(3) NOT NULL,
 5  PRIMARY KEY(custId),
 6  CONSTRAINT chk_CustomerAge CHECK (custAge < 100)
 7  );
```

I have this error

```
 4  custAge INTEGER(3) NOT NULL,
 ERROR at line 4:
 ORA-00904: : Invalid Indentifier
```

I tried doing this also

```
SQL > CREATE TABLE Customer (
 2  custId INT NOT NULL,
 3  custName VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
 4  custAge INTEGER(3) NOT NULL,
 5  PRIMARY KEY(custId),
 6  CONSTRAINT chk_CustomerAge CHECK (custAge < 100)
 7  );
```

But I am still getting the same error and I have no idea why.

Comment: use `integer` which is a synonym for `number` - for details on available data types see the manual. And integers don't have a "size" (neither do they in MySQL `int(3)` doesn't do anything there)

Comment: Well.. `INT(3)` sets the default width on columns for unbuffered query output to 3... But is has nothing to do with size in MySQL indeed.